# $http request not running test for service

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I have the following test for a service object and the promise doesn't return and neither does the http request get called from inside the service, but it works in browser testing.

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: AuthService', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('adminPanelAngularApp'));

  var AuthService, AuthService, $rootScope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function (_AuthService_, _$rootScope_) {
    AuthService = _AuthService_;

    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

  }));

  it('it auths', function () {
    AuthService.login(SOMECREDENTIALS).then(function(){
      console.log('this doesnt output in log');
    });

    expect(3).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

this is my service

```
angular.module('adminPanelAngularApp').factory('AuthService', ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$location', '$q', function ($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $location, $q) {
  var authService = {};

  ....

  authService.get_current_user = function(){
    return $rootScope.current_user;
  }

  authService.login = function (credentials) {
    var url = REDACTED;

    return $http.post(server+url).then(function (res) {
      if (!res.data){
        return false;
      }

      if (res.data.error){
        $rootScope.login_error = res.data.error;
      }

      var user = {
        email: res.data.email,
        session: res.data.session,
        uid: res.data.uid
      }

      $cookieStore.put('loginData', user);
      $rootScope.current_user = user;

      return user;
    });
  };

...
```

what am I doing wrong with the tests?

I know my code is pretty bad too, but if I can test this then i'm halfway there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to mock `$http`, I suggest you to use `$httpBackend`.

With `$httpBackend` you can mock the calls you make with `$http`.

Imagine this service:

```
app.factory('Auth', function($http) {
  return {
    login: function() {
      return $http.post('/login');
    }
  };
});
```

The goal is to test that you make your `$http.post` and it returns successfully, so the idea is like:

```
describe('Service: Auth', function() {
  var Auth, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');

    inject(function(_Auth_, _$httpBackend_) {
      Auth = _Auth_;

      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

      $httpBackend.whenPOST('/login').respond(200);
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('should do a proper login', function() {
    var foo;

    Auth.login().then(function() {
      foo = "success";
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(foo).toBe("success");
  });

});
```

So, for starters, we inject what we need (`Auth` and `$httpBackend`)

And then, we call the `whenPOST` of `$httpBackend`. Basically it does something like:

> When someone does a POST to `/login`, respond it with 200

Then on the test, we call `login` which is going to do the `$http.post`. To process this `$http.post`, since it is async, we can *simulate* the real call doing a `$httpBackend.flush()` which is going to "process" the call.

After that, we can verify that the `.then` was executed.

What about the `afterEach`? We don't really need it for this example, but when you want to assert yes or yes that a call was made, you can change the `whenPOST` to `expectPOST`, to make a test fail if that `POST` is never made. The afterEach is basically checking the status of the `$httpBackend` to see if any of those expectation weren't matched.

On the other hand, you don't need to create a promise by hand. `$http` returns a promise for you, so you can return the `$http` call directly, and on the `$http` `then` you can:

```
return user;
```

That will simplify the implementation a little bit.

Demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6DFmmLKXCvFkrOGTAqC?p=preview)

Comment: i wanted to start off with doing the real requests to begin with.

Comment: remove promise usage from my original question as i was trying to force a result through without knowing what angular did with the backend. I'd like a solution where I could use a real request till i'm happy with my spec and save them as mocks.

Comment: No, that is not correct. That is a unit test, which is mean to test the factory isolated from the rest of the world. Never ever do real request on a unit test. That is completely wrong. In fact, angular-mock has code to prevent that from happening (there are workarounds though).

Comment: I want to do it "wrong" so that I can extract the real world response and put it into the test from the test suite and not have to use anything else like postman or curl. cheers.